# Using a converted Unix Timestamp to query the database

Tags: php, mysql, unix, timestamp, timetable

I am currently using this:

```
$rawsql = "SELECT 
*
FROM 
    _erc_foffices n 
INNER JOIN 
    _erc_openings o ON n.id = o.branch_id AND o.dotw = DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_DATE()) 
INNER JOIN 
    _erc_openings_times t ON o.id = t.opening_id
WHERE 
(
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) BETWEEN 
        UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(CURRENT_DATE(), ' ', t.open))
    AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(CURRENT_DATE(), ' ', t.close)) 
) 
AND 
(
    n.id = %d
)
    ;";
```

to query the database, and return all of the details from the embassy if it is currently open.

Now, rather than the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`, I need to find out whether the time stored in variable `$current_local_time` is between the 2 database values. Timetable times need to be stored in local times instead of London's times, so that's why I'm trying to convert them.

I have tried replacing the

```
WHERE 
    (
        UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) BETWEEN
            UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(CURRENT_DATE(), ' ', t.open))
        AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(CURRENT_DATE(), ' ', t.close)) 
    )
```

with

```
WHERE 
    (
        UNIX_TIMESTAMP($current_local_time) BETWEEN 
            UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(CURRENT_DATE(), ' ', t.open)) 
        AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(CURRENT_DATE(), ' ', t.close)) 
    )
```

but I just get error messages. Could someone please tell me how I would do this properly?

Thanks for any help

Edit: The `$current_local_time` variable is taken like so:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$time = date("H:i", time());
$myDateTime = new DateTime($time, new DateTimeZone('GMT'));
$myDateTime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($timezone));
$current_local_time = $myDateTime->format('H:i:s');
```

and outputs as whatever the current time in the other country is when echoed.

Edit 2:

I have changed the $current_local_time to this:

```
$current_local_time = $myDateTime->format('H:i:s');
$timestamp2 = strtotime($current_local_time);
```

and the where clause to this:

```
WHERE 
(
    '$timestamp2' BETWEEN 
        UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(CURRENT_DATE(), ' ', t.open)) 
    AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(CURRENT_DATE(), ' ', t.close)) 
)
```

This works OK, but if `t.close` is set at 23:30, it won't actually shut until 23:31. Is there a way to take a minute off of the captured time to sort this out?

Comment: What are the error messages you get?

Comment: Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in E:\wamp\www\app\webroot\erc\index.php on line 185

Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in E:\wamp\www\app\webroot\erc\index.php on line 197

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timestamp that you're inserting needs to be quoted as a string, so you need

```
WHERE 
    (
        UNIX_TIMESTAMP('$current_local_time') BETWEEN 
            UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(CURRENT_DATE(), ' ', t.open)) 
        AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(CURRENT_DATE(), ' ', t.close)) 
    )
```

It's even better to use a SQL framework that lets you do parameter binding, specify the query as follows, and bind the `?` to `$current_local_time` in PHP.

```
WHERE 
    (
        UNIX_TIMESTAMP(?) BETWEEN 
            UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(CURRENT_DATE(), ' ', t.open)) 
        AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(CURRENT_DATE(), ' ', t.close)) 
    )
```

EDIT: I think you want

```
(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(CURRENT_DATE(), ' ', t.open))     <=   '$timestamp2'
AND
'$timestamp2'    <    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(CURRENT_DATE(), ' ', t.close)))
--              ^^^ Note the less-than sign
```

You probably don't need quotes around `$timestamp2` anymore.

Comment: Hi Ken, I have added the single quotes around the variable name, but the query isn't returning any results. The $current_local_time is currently set at 22:50 (Vietnam time), and the opening hours I have set to 23:59 tonight, so it should show as open if a result is returned. Is there something else I need to change? Thanks for your help

Comment: 22:50 is before 23:59, so it's not in the opening hours. (Unless you meant that `t.close` is 23:59).

Comment: Sorry I should of been clearer, I did mean that t.close is 23:59. I think I have got it working now using the single quotes, but I have had to remove the UNIX_TIMESTAMP. I will update my post with what I have at the moment...just testing it at the minute

Comment: Hi ken, I have updated my question. Do you know the answer to the bottom part? Thanks

Comment: @user: Really, you should post a new question for something like that. The answer is that `expr BETWEEN min AND max` is equivalent to `(min <= expr AND expr <= max)`. If you want something different, you have to spell out the comparison operators, and skip the `BETWEEN`.